# Can't select textbox on browser resize

Tags: css, browser

I have a web forms site and randomly certain rows or individual text boxes will be inhibited from selection to obtain focus.  The cursor never changes from an arrow to a text pipe at the boundary of the textbox.  Sometimes the change from pointer to text pipe will occur in the middle of the textbox.  If I resize the browswer window I can change this behavior.  Generally running the browswer maximized makes this go away.  I've searched for this and I've not found anything similar on SO, or maybe I'm using the wrong search terms.

[image: Web Form Example]
<sub>(source: [uber-writer.com](http://uber-writer.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/SchCIncomeForm.png))</sub>

The image shows a typical table with some hypothetical data.  The "Amortization Exp" row is causing issues. Shown below is the table markup:

```
<table class="incomeDataEntryTblNarrow_wTotal">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Tax Year:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_oneYearAgoYear" Text='<%# Eval("oneYearAgoYear") %>' runat="server" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSchedC_prevYear" runat="server" Text="INVLD" Font-Size="10"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            W2 Line 5:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_w2box5_OneYearAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("w2box5_OneYearAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_w2box5_TwoYearsAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("w2box5_TwoYearsAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox"  ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Line 6<br />Other Income:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Line6_OneYearAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("line6_OneYearAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" onkeydown="return jsDecimalsRO(event);" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Line6_TwoYearsAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("line6_TwoYearsAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox"  onkeydown="return jsDecimalsRO(event);" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Line 12<br />Depletion:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Line12_OneYearAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("line12_OneYearAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Line12_TwoYearsAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("line12_TwoYearsAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Line 13<br />Depreciation:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Line13_OneYearAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("line13_OneYearAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Line13_TwoYearsAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("line13_TwoYearsAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Line 24b<br />Meals & Entertainment:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Line24b_OneYearAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("line24b_OneYearAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Line24b_TwoYearsAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("line24b_TwoYearsAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Line 30<br />Expenses Home Use:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Line30_OneYearAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("line30_OneYearAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Line30_TwoYearsAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("line30_TwoYearsAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Line 31<br />Net Profit:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Line31_OneYearAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("line31_OneYearAgo")) %>' runat="server" CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Line31_TwoYearsAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("line31_TwoYearsAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Amortization Exp<br />Part V:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Amort_OneYearAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("Amortization_OneYearAgo")) %>' runat="server" CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Amort_TwoYearsAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("Amortization_TwoYearsAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Casualty Loss<br />Part V:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Casualty_OneYearAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("Casualty_OneYearAgo")) %>' runat="server" CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Casualty_TwoYearsAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("Casualty_TwoYearsAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Other Exp<br />Part V:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Other_OneYearAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("OtherExp_OneYearAgo")) %>' runat="server" CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Other_TwoYearsAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("OtherExp_TwoYearsAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Business Miles<br />Part IV Linve44a:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_BizMiles_OneYearAgo" Text='<%# Eval("BizMiles_OneYearAgo") %>' runat="server" CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_BizMiles_TwoYearsAgo" Text='<%# Eval("BizMiles_TwoYearsAgo") %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Total Income:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblFinalIncomeY1" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("finalIncomeY1")) %>' runat="server" Font-Size="12px"  width="75" style="text-align:right;"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblFinalIncomeY2" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("finalIncomeY2")) %>' runat="server" Font-Size="12px"  width="75" style="text-align:right;"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS for the textbox is here

```
.incomeTextBox {
    width: 85px;
    text-align: right;
    cursor: text;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

I removed the whitespace and tried the site and got the same response.

```
<table class="incomeDataEntryTblNarrow_wTotal">
<tr>
    <td>Tax Year:</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_oneYearAgoYear" Text='<%# Eval("oneYearAgoYear") %>' runat="server" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td><asp:Label ID="lblSchedC_prevYear" runat="server" Text="INVLD" Font-Size="10"></asp:Label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>W2 Line 5:</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_w2box5_OneYearAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("w2box5_OneYearAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" ></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_w2box5_TwoYearsAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("w2box5_TwoYearsAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox"  ></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Line 6<br />Other Income:</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Line6_OneYearAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("line6_OneYearAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox" onkeydown="return jsDecimalsRO(event);" ></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSchedC_Line6_TwoYearsAgo" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}",Eval("line6_TwoYearsAgo")) %>' runat="server"  CssClass="incomeTextBox"  onkeydown="return jsDecimalsRO(event);" ></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If I had to guess I would say it's because of the whitespace in your html. Perhaps try eliminating it and seeing if the cursor problem is fixed. Also, you shouldn't have to set the cursor on an input box since it defaults to the text cursor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I just tried that and it didn't change the outcome.  Do you know what governs the hotspot for a textbox and how that could differ from the rendered textbox itself?

Comment: Maybe try adding a height and display to your class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer ended up being a wrapper div around a UpdateProgress message box.

```
<%--        <div class="processingStatus">--%>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div class="processingMessage processingStatus">
                    Updating...
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
<%--        </div>  --%>
```

In the snippet I have commented out the wrapper div.  The .css for the wrapper div was essentially creating a transparent div that would block anything that came behind it.  This explains why the problem appeared to be random and would change when the screen was re-sized.  The style on the UpdateProgress would have the message be centered on the screen, but the content on the screen isn't centered.  I ended up killing the wrapper div and moving the css class to the div inside the ProgressTemplate.  Deployed the change and it works as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this overlapping issue by fixing the table width 
say for example

```
table
{
width:600px;
}
```

it will fix overlapping issue on resizing the browser 
but you need to scroll right to see rest of data

Comment: Naveen, thanks for the suggestion.  It turns out it was a wrapper div for my UpdateProgress message box.  The wrapper div style was blocking out a small area of the screen and whatever textbox slid behind that div would become blocked.  Hence the random feel to the problem.